# $\log (1+x)$ when $x$ is $p$-adic

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

It's written when $x$ is $p$-adic integer then $\log (1+x) = \sum (-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}$ converges, I don't understand what this statement mean. Can one please explain me ?

Comment: It's written where? It's not true that it converges for all $p$-adic $x$.

Comment: It only converges when $|x|_p<1$.

Comment: So, what part of the above are you having trouble with? Do you know what $p$-adic numbers are? Do you not know what convergence means in $p$-adic numbers? Do you know these things, but don't know how to prove this particular series converges? You really need to help people help you.

Comment: I only know definition of a $p$-aidic number, dunno anything about convergence in $p$-aidic numbers. Can you provide a reference to it ?

Comment: Sorry, it was also provided $p|x$

Comment: Okay, got it now.

Answer (score 1):

In the standard setting we are most used to we say that a sequence of real numbers $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to a real number $x$ if 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n - x| = 0$$
where $|\cdot|$ is the absolute value norm. Convergence of a sequence of $p$-adic numbers is defined the same way, but with $|\cdot|$ being the [$p$-adic norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/p-adicNorm.html) (and $x_n,x$ being $p$-adic numbers).

In practice the [Cauchy-criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence) for convergence is perhaps more useful as a working definition (and again with $|\cdot|$ being the $p$-adic norm).

---

Before you try to solve this problem I would strongly suggest you make yourself familiar with the $p$-adic numbers by solving some simpler problem. A quick google search gives many introductions, for example [this](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~ajb/dvi-ps/padicnotes.pdf).  Anyway, here are some hints:

One very useful fact to solve the problem at hand is this: a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ of $p$-adic numbers converges iff $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n|_p = 0$. This result (try to prove it) is a consequence of the non-achimedian property $|x+y|_p \leq \text{max}(|x|_p,|y|_p)$ of the [$p$-adic norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/p-adicNorm.html).

Thus you need to show that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n}\right|_p = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(|x|_p \cdot \left|\frac{1}{n}\right|_p^{1/n}\right)^n = 0$$

if $x$ is a $p$-adic integer. If you now can prove the following two things

1. If $x$ is a [$p$-adic integer](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/p-adicInteger.html) with $p|x$ then $|x|_p< 1$
2. $\limsup_{n\to\infty} |1/n|_p^{1/n} = 1$.

then the desired result follows. Some hints: for 1. try to use the non-archimedian property mentioned above togeather with the definition of a $p$-adic integer and norm.

Comment: Actually, if $x$ is a $p$-adic integer, then $|x|_p\leq 1$. You need $x=py$ for $y$ a $p$-adic integer to get $|x|<1$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Indeed, thanks. I also see OP added this as a condition.

Comment: Yes. Irritatingly, he didn't actually add it to the question, just noted it in a comment.